# Ability to review questions being transferred from SO before they appear

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, moderation

A significant proportion of questions being transferred here from SO are being closed pretty rapidly upon arrival.

Would it be possible to have them transfer to a holding area where they can be reviewed (by mods or suitably rep-ed up users - appearing in the tools area) prior to appearing on the site?  I'd suggest a threshold of two (or more) users have to accept the question.

If it's accepted then it appears as normal, if not then it gets returned to SO closed with a comment explaining what's happened.

EDIT: Can I just highlight in light of: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/88846/what-are-you-doing-with-cables-under-workrtable

This is a question which should obviously be shut rather than migrated anywhere. If SO can't give it more thought then this then the migration functionality should be disabled.

Comment: Meta.SO would get better comments and attention

Comment: This has been raised several times on Meta.SO and rejected every time. Can't hurt (much) to bring it up again. FWIW, I support some form of an arrangement like that.

Comment: I've suggested something like this on chat, but not followed it through with a proper question on MSO so I'd support a feature request along these lines. One thing to add might be that the question only goes into holding if the vote to migrate isn't unanimous.

Comment: @ChrisF - I'm guessing that it would be easy enough for someone to write a script to see if there is a difference in the percentage of questions that get closed after being migrated unanimously, against those where it wasn't unanimous?  I'd suggest that they should only be treated differently if there is a significant difference in the outcomes for the two scenarios.

Comment: Maybe the people (mods and high-rep users) should be educated about the rules at P.SE, so they know that some questions should be closed instead of migrated.

Comment: @ammoQ Mods talk and SO mods often check with us before migrating a question. For high-rep users... it's unreasonable to expect every 3k+ user to be educated on how PSE works. I think the best we can do for educating people is getting our tagline corrected and SO's FAQ clarified. See [here](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/1838/proposal-for-inserting-a-so-xor-pe-sentence-in-the-faq) for the proposal.

Comment: See discussion [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97157/ability-to-review-questions-being-transferred-from-so-before-they-appear) on MSO.

Comment: Ugh, that's not even a programmers specific question and likely should have gone to Superuser.

Comment: @Rob - I'm not sure it's even a superuser question. DIY.SE?

Answer (score 5):

As [Anna mentioned in the comments](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1211/ability-to-review-questions-being-transferred-from-so-before-they-appear#comment2894_1211), similar feature requests come up from time to time on [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) and—while popular—almost never get a warm response from Stack Exchange. This request should be another example of that. :P

I've heard rumors that migrations will be tackled some time this year, so while it's unlikely this specific feature would ever be implemented, hopefully another, comparable solution will be implemented in the future.